# need with testing my model on react natiev app

Tags: python, pandas, garbage

I was trying to build a ML proj on kaggle notebook after trying several datsets I finally created one of my own and did with the labelling but to no avail I want mine to give me a validation to if a pic given to it is actually a pic of a waste or not[so it should give a yes or no kinda answer that's it] but sersly I am unable to find the models or even any ipynb notebook anywhere that gave the same results? can someone suggest me something that I can link to my react native app to test if it is really working ?

I have tried several notebooks online